# using ajax to get data and update form field

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I added this code in the head:

```
<script>
function cpf(pag) {
    request = createRequest();
    if(request == null) {
        alert("Unable to Create Request");
        return;
    }
    var nocache = new Date();
    var url = "https://pathto.com/cp/gettime.php?t="+pag;
    url = url + "&stopIEcache="+ nocache;
    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.onreadystatechange = showtpage;
    request.send(null);
}

function showtpage() {
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
        if(request.status == 200) {
            detailDiv = document.getElementByName("newtdf")[0];
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function createRequest() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (otherMS) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return request;
}

</script>
```

Here is my HTML output by php:

```
<input type="text" value="2014/10/10 05:08" id="datetimepicker" name="newtd" onBlur="cpf(document.getElementByName('newtd')[0].value);" /><br />
Epoch Timestamp Built: <input type="text" name="newtdf" size="10" value="">
```

So I have the first field that is selectable by a datetimepicker, when they leave the field (onblur), it should run the cpf function I created on the script, and pass the value of the field to it.

But it is not working.

I ran it and with the debugger, it says this:

```
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

can you help me fix it please?

Comment: I also tried this function in place of the other one:

function showtpage() {
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
        if(request.status == 200) {
            detailDiv = document.getElementByName("newtdf");
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}
That did not work either, same error on the console.

Comment: which line is giving that error?

Comment: @Darren -> I put it on the comment below... sorry, I did not see you asked that.

Answer (score 0):

Try declaring the request variable before, like the code below:

```
<script>
var request;
function cpf(pag) {
    request = createRequest();
    if(request == null) {
        alert("Unable to Create Request");
        return;
    }
    var nocache = new Date();
    var url = "https://pathto.com/cp/gettime.php?t="+pag;
    url = url + "&stopIEcache="+ nocache;
    request.open("GET",url,true);
    request.onreadystatechange = showtpage;
    request.send(null);
}

function showtpage() {
    if(request.readyState == 4) {
        if(request.status == 200) {
            detailDiv = document.getElementByName("newtdf")[0];
            detailDiv.innerHTML = request.responseText;
        }
    }
}

function createRequest() {
    try {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    } catch (tryMS) {
        try {
            request = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        } catch (otherMS) {
            try {
                request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
            } catch (failed) {
                request = null;
            }
        }
    }
    return request;
}

</script>
```

Comment: That did not fix it either. the undefined error did go away, but it still is not doing anything.

Comment: Do you know which line is giving the error? Or do you have the script running on any URL?

Comment: I see this error now:
Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function time-tracking?viewClockedIn=1&editClockInTD=2:318
onblur time-tracking?viewClockedIn=1&editClockInTD=2:318

so it must be line 318, which is this line:
<input type="text" value="2014/10/10 05:08" id="datetimepicker" name="newtd" onBlur="cpf(document.getElementByName('newtd')[0].value);" />

Comment: You're probably including the script after you've tried to call it, meaning it'd throw that error up @RichardJones

Comment: The script is in between the <head and </head.... tags

The call on it, is after the <body tag. so how could that cause the error?